# After enabling multiple push notifications in android phonegap app, only latest notification data is available

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, push

Push Notification PhoneGap - With reference to http://www.pushwoosh.com/enable-multiple-notifications-in-android/
I am getting Multiple Notifications in the status bar, however only latest notification data is available.

Is their any way to get specific notification data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle multiple push notification of pushplugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533796/how-to-handle-multiple-push-notification-of-pushplugin)